# Add a custom header to $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

I have a factory with a number of functions that look like this,

```
doFunction: function () {
   return $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'https://localhost:8000/test',
       data: {},
       headers: {
          "My_Header": $rootScope.value,
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
       }
    })
}
```

I want to add a custom header called `My_Header`, but I dont think this is the correct way of doing it since it is not included on the request. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What if you change the name to "My-Header" (or MyHeader)? I couldn't find the required format for header names, but if it is actually not showing up as a request header as you say, then it could be because chrome doesn't like the look of it, although I couldn't find any reason why your code shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `HttpHeaders()` from [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http).

Then add your header: `.append('My_Header', $rootScope.value)`.

Now use these new headers for your request.

Comment: Odd this was the accepted answer seeing how [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers) let you pass in a plain object

Comment: `HttpHeaders` is an Angular 2+ class. Why would adding it to AngularJS solve the problem?